# Efficient evaluation of an integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I wish to use Mathematica to evaluate f(x; y) defined by the integral

$$f(x;y)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{4ue^{-2u}(1-e^{-2xu})}{1-y^{2}e^{-2xu}}\,du$$

and plot $f$ as function of $x$ for different values of the parameter $y$..

Apparently, naively asking Mathematica to evaluate this integral requires a lot of time. Is there any way to speed up the computations?

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: F[x_, y_] := 
 Integrate[ (4*
     u)*(Exp[-2 u]*((1 - Exp[-2*x*u])/(1 - (y^2)*Exp[-2*x*u]))), {u, 
   0, Infinity}]

plot[F[x, 0.1], {x, 0.1, 0.5}]

Comment: Thank you. I have posted all the code. "u" is just an integration variable. There is no prior definition of the variable u.

Comment: What?  You state that `u` is an integration variable, but instead your code integrates `x`?!?

Comment: My code does integrate the variable u. The x is treated as an external parameter in the process of integration. I wish to obtain the integral as a function of x (after integrating out u) and graph it versus x.

Comment: When I put  F[0.5,0.5], Mathematica even returns a complex number with a very small imaginary component ...

Comment: You should investigate your integrand looking for singularities for $a$ and $b$ values, and for valid ranges as well...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: I can't see any problem at all. If other people need help, they could raise questions of their own. Of course, I would be happy to make the contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Giving [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) assumptions about `x` and `y` yields:

```
f[x_,y_] = Integrate[
    (4 u Exp[-2u](1-Exp[-2 x u]))/(1 - y^2 Exp[-2 x u]),
    {u,0,Infinity},
    Assumptions -> x>0 && -1<y<1
]
```

> (x^2 + (-1 + y^2) LerchPhi[y^2, 2, 1/x])/(x^2 y^2)

A couple quick numerical checks:

```
g[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[
    (4 u Exp[-2u](1-Exp[-2 x u]))/(1 - y^2 Exp[-2 x u]),
    {u, 0, Infinity}
]

f[.5, .5]
g[.5, .5]

f[.2, .6]
g[.2, .6]
```

> 0.610693
>
> 0.610693
>
> 0.392552
>
> 0.392552

Visualization:

```
Plot[{f[x, .1], f[x, .5], f[x, .9]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        F[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
        NIntegrate[(4*
      u)*(Exp[-2 u]*((1 - Exp[-2*x*u])/(1 - (y^2)*Exp[-2*x*u]))), {u, 
     0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
     Plot[Evaluate@Table[F[x, y], {y, .1, .9, .4}], {x, 0, 5}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 15], Style["F ", 15]}, 
     PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[{.1, .5, .9}, LegendLabel -> "y", 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"], {{0.78, .40}, {0.45, .65}}], 
    ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: modified plot]

Comment: Why do you use `F[y_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ]` instead of `F[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ]`?

Comment: Thnaks@woll, I have edited the code.